# Error: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, tbb, lvalue

I have been getting this error come up in the for loop when I try to assign values to x_dev, y_dev, and pearson. As far as I can see they should all be modifiable. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

```
class LoopBody
{  
    double *const x_data;
    double *const y_data;
    double const x_mean;
    double const y_mean;  
    double x_dev;
    double y_dev;
    double pearson; 


public:
    LoopBody(double *x, double *y, double xmean, double ymean, double xdev, double ydev, double pear) 
            : x_data(x), y_data(y), x_mean(xmean), y_mean(ymean), x_dev(xdev), y_dev(ydev), pearson(pear) {}  

    void operator() (const blocked_range<size_t> &r) const {              
        for(size_t i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); i++)
        {
            double x_temp = x_data[i] - x_mean;
            double y_temp = y_data[i] - y_mean;

            x_dev += x_temp * x_temp;
            y_dev += y_temp * y_temp;

            pearson += x_temp * y_temp;

        }
    }
};
```

Having followed @Bathsheba 's advice I have overcome these problems. However When running a parallel_for the operator is runs but the for loop is never entered.

This is where I call the parallel_for:

```
parallel_for(blocked_range<size_t>(0,n), LoopBody(x, y, x_mean, y_mean, x_dev, y_dev, pearson), auto_partitioner());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `()` operator is marked `const`, and you're attempting to modify class member data (e.g. `x_dev`, `y_dev` and `person`). That is not allowed and is why you're getting the compile-time error.

You probably want to drop the `const` from the method.

Alternatively you can mark the member data that you want to modify as `mutable`, but this is not the preferred solution as it makes code brittle, difficult to read and can wreak havoc with multi-threading.

Comment: This fixes that problem but I am now given an error when compiling:


c:\program files (x86)\tbb41\include\tbb\parallel_for.h(110): error C3848: expression having type 'const LoopBody' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'void LoopBody::operator ()(const tbb::blocked_range<Value> &)'



Googling this says that the fix would be to include the const I just deleted.

Comment: The problem is that `()` is not supposed to modify class member data. Why do you need to do that? If you *really* need to then, perhaps, making the class members `mutable` and marking the function `const` *is* the way forward. But I do not like that for the reasons I state in the answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right that `()` is not supposed to modify class members, in particular because `tbb::parallel_for` uses multiple instances of the body, and anything accumulated in a single instance will just be lost. Thus, the combination of `const` and `mutable` will only hide the real problem. The proper solution is to use `tbb::parallel_reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

Seemingly you want to do reduction, i.e. compute some aggregate values over the data.

For that, TBB offers a special function template: `parallel_reduce`. Unlike `parallel_for` that perhaps you use now, `parallel_reduce` does not require `operator()` of a body class to be const, because an instance of that class accumulates partial results. However, it poses other requirements to the class: the need to have a special constructor as well as a method to merge partial results from another body instance.

More information can be found in the Intel(R) TBB User Guide: http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/parallel_reduce.htm

Also there is an overload of `parallel_reduce` which takes two functors - one for body and another one for merging partial results - as well as a special "identity" value used to initialize accumulators. But you are computing three aggregate values at once, so you would still need to have a struct or class to store all three values in a single variable.